# Monte Carlo Algorithms : Are there any problems where two opposite Monte Carlo algorithms could solve it?

Tags: probabilistic-algorithms, monte-carlo

I started reading on Probabilistic algorithms and Monte-Carlo algorithms. Since a Monte-Carlo can only give a certain answer for either True or False, I was wondering if it's conceivable that **for the same problem**, there exist two opposite Monte-Carlo Algorithms capable of giving a certain answer. (By opposite, I mean one would be sure when it's FALSE, and the other would be certain when it's TRUE)

**For example** : There exist a prime number test Monte-Carlo based algorithm that can check whether or not a number "n" is prime. If the answer is FALSE, then "n" is not a prime number (it is a composed number). However, if the answer were to be TRUE, then "n" COULD be prime (with a certain probability). To my knowledge, there is no efficient algorithm (Monte-Carlo) capable of saying with certainty if "n" is a prime number.

Comment: Such problems correspond to Las Vegas algorithm, as expressed by the identity $\mathsf{ZPP}=\mathsf{RP} \cap \mathsf{coRP}$. See for example the [Wikipedia page on ZPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZPP_(complexity)).

Comment: Your example is a bit problematic, since primality can be tested in *deterministic* polynomial time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *Las Vegas algorithm* is one which is always correct, but is only efficient in expectation. Given two "opposite" Monte Carlo algorithm, you can create a Las Vegas algorithm by alternating both algorithms (or running them in parallel), halting whenever one of them produces a certain answer.

In the language of complexity theory, this corresponds to the statement $\mathsf{ZPP} = \mathsf{RP} \cap \mathsf{coRP}$. You can find more information on $\mathsf{ZPP}$ on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZPP_(complexity)).

Comment: Interesting link, thank you! So given enough time, the answer is sure to come out? I was under the impression that Las Vegas could be unable to answer (LV always gives the right answer, or it doesn't answer)

Comment: @Robert maybe you could consider accepting this answer?